# Background overlay on hover

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have markup like this but also background overlay on hover?

```
<figure class="gallery-item">
    <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
        </a>
    </div>
</figure>
```

I tried placing `background-color: #333` on `.gallery-icon` on hover, but only something like border-bottom appears?

http://codepen.io/filaret/pen/NRpVyr

Comment: insert your code in a snippet to see the modifications you used please

Comment: You also can create a div between div.gallery-item and div.gallery-icon landscape (lets call it back2) with the desired background and perform a translation on hover or something similar. Or use a semi-transparent image and set back2 opacity 0 and change to 1 on hover (if the img is 60% opacity and you set a full black background, you'll get a visible overlay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track. Since you are using an `:after` element for the icon, you should leave that element alone since it's already positioned and defining its own width+height (based off the icon).

The reason the `:after` selector positions itself correctly is because it's not relying on its parent containers dimensions. You only have it as absolute from the top and left, which is fine. But it doesn't know about how tall it should be, because its parent has no defined height! If you use absolute positioning, you need to define the parent containers dimensions so that the child knows where its bounds are.

So first off, `.gallery-icon` is already a block element, so you don't need to define its width (its already 100% by nature), just the height:

```
 .gallery-icon {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
 }
```

Second, you should use a `:before` element to define a background, so that you don't have to mess with the `:after` icon:

```
 &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Now, you just have to add the opacity change on hover!

```
 &:hover {
    .gallery-icon {
       &:before {
          opacity: .5;
       }
       &:after {
          opacity: 0.6;
       }
    }
```

Hope that helps, here is a codepen forked off your original: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRWqxX

Edit: I also noticed that your `img` tag is causing it to go below the visual bottom of the container, a quick fix is just to add:

```
  .gallery-icon {
     img {
        display: block;
     }
```

Comment: I should also add that you don't *always* need to define the height and width of parent elements, but you are just relying on the fact that every renderer will treat it the same, which is a bad assumption!

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand your markup works. Your image will be displayed on top of everything, and when you put a background colour on .gallery-icon that background colour will be under the image, and since the anchor link doesn't has a width and height, it only take a little bit of portion, that's why it showing a border bottom.

To create a background overlay on hover, you need to position it to be on top of the image.

Using pseudo element to create a background overlay:

```
&:hover .gallery-icon {
  &::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #333; 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}
```

The pseudo element has a position absolute so it will displayed on top of the image. top, left, right and bottom 0 to tell the pseudo element to stretch it self as tall and as wide as the parent element.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to simplify the code a little bit. I hope it's what you've tried to achieve.

The trick is to place `a` as a independent element to `img`.

```
<figure class="gallery-item">
    <a href="www.google.com"></a>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</figure>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRWoaR

Comment: I can't change html, it is Wordpress default

Answer (score -1):

The image (http://placehold.it/300x300) has a solid background colour, no?

That will block anything happening behind itself.